# UDP socket: server sending file to client Address family not supported by protocol family

Tags: c, sockets, udp

I am just a beginner in socket programming and currently working on an small program dealing with file transfer using UDP. This program is written in C.

Here is my problem:
UDP server will first use the recvfrom() function to catch message from UDP client so to start sending a file. I sent the file name first, and it couldn't went through, appearing with: *Address family not supported by protocol family* as the error message(). I checked the sin_family of client_addr, and it is 7. Furthermore, after I tried to set *client_addr.sin_family = AF_INET*; the server worked fine, except that the client couldn't even receive any message.

I have checked some sources but it happened to be not so helpful, please if anyone knows why and willing to tell. Appreciate all your help.

Below is a short portion of server code:

```
int socketfd;
/* my address information */
struct sockaddr_in server_addr;
/* connector’s address information */
struct sockaddr_in client_addr;
socklen_t clientLength;
int numbytes;
char buffer[BUFLEN];
int portNum = atoi(port);
time_t timer;
char charfileSize[20];
int percent, count = 0;
struct tm *tm_info;
char timeBuf[30];
if((socketfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP)) == -1) {
  perror("Server-socket() sockfd error lol!");
  exit(1);
} else {
  printf("Server-socket() sockfd is OK...\n");
}

server_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
server_addr.sin_port = htons(portNum);
server_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
memset(&(server_addr.sin_zero), 0, 8);

// bind the socket to the server ip address
if(bind(socketfd, (struct sockaddr *)&server_addr, sizeof(struct sockaddr)) == -1) {
  perror("server socket bind to IP error lol!\n");
  exit(1);
} else {
  printf("successfully bind server ip with socket ...\n");
}
// client_addr.sin_port = htons(portNum);
client_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;

//*  for ensuring client connection  *//
int tempGet;
char tempBuf[BUFLEN];
//if( (tempGet = recvfrom(socketfd, tempBuf, BUFLEN, 0, (struct sockaddr *)&client_addr, &clientLength)) > 0 ) {
tempGet = recvfrom(socketfd, tempBuf, BUFLEN, 0, (struct sockaddr *)&client_addr, &clientLength);
if( strcmp( tempBuf, "send file" ) == 0) {
  printf("Can start transferring file...\n");
}
printf("sin family:%d\n", client_addr.sin_family);

FILE *fp = fopen(filename, "rb");
if ( !fp ) {
  perror("Error opening the file\n");
  exit(1);
} else {
  // successfully opened the file that's going to be transferred
  printf("file opened: %s\n", filename);

  // get file size
  int file_block_size = 0;
  bzero(buffer, BUFLEN);
  long file_size;
  fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_END);
  file_size = ftell(fp);
  // goes back to the beginning of file(fp)
  rewind(fp);
  printf("file name: %s\n", filename);
  printf("file size: %ld kb\n", file_size/1024);
  // get time
  time(&timer);
  clientLength = sizeof(client_addr);

  //client_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
  int sendFileName;
  // length of file name
  if( (sendFileName = sendto(socketfd, filename, strlen(filename), 0, (struct sockaddr *)&client_addr, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in))) >= 0) {
    printf("file name sent.\n");
  } else {
    //printf("%d\n", sendFileName);
    perror("file name send error.\n");
    exit(1);
  }
}
```

Comment: One generally passes `0` as the third argument to `socket()`.  The chosen combination of address family and socket type rarely affords more than one protocol, and when it doesn't, `0` selects the single available protocol.  Doing this helps avoids mistakes.

Comment: Where is the problem reported - in the client or server? I do not see socket creation code for the client.

Comment: Are you sure about the client side code?

Comment: Thanks @JohnBollinger, i tried.... but well it didn't solve the problem.

Comment: I also do not recommend sending file using UDP without additional checks. You are likely to loose packets.

Comment: @SergeyA, I think the problem is on the server side. And I put those additional code on.

Comment: @SergeyA it's actually an assignment so it is required to use UDP, so to check the packet loss rate.

Comment: @Boopslo, it is not 'what you think'. You should be able to tell with absolute certainty which part of code displays the problem.

Comment: @Boopslo, when you say you *think* the problem is on the server side, do you mean that's where the error is reported?  Where in the code is the error generated?

Comment: Ok, before I tried to set client_addr.sin_family = AF_INET; , the error happened on the server side, which is where the error was generated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The last argument to `recvfrom` takes the address of a `socklen_t` which needs to be initialized with the size of the sockaddr parameter.  I don't see `clientLength` initialized prior to this call, so `client_addr` is probably not being updated properly when this function returns.  This causes the subsequent call to `sendto` to fail.

If you initialize `clientLength` before calling `recvfrom` that will take care of the problem.

```
clientLength = sizeof(client_addr);
tempGet = recvfrom(socketfd, tempBuf, BUFLEN, 0, (struct sockaddr *)&client_addr, &clientLength);
```

Comment: Thank you @dbush, that is exactly where the problem was... cuz the  initialization part of code is after receiving from buffer.

Answer (score 0):

I am slightly tired of all incorrect and half-correct UDP socket program attempts at Stack Overflow. I have decided to do the reference UDP implementation, taking this question as an example. Next time I see TCP question (and have some time and energy) I will do reference TCP implementation.

This implementation does everything correctly (to the best of my knowledge :). It uses BSD sockets, so Windows implementations will have to make minor changes. Other than that, it should be C-99 conforiming in all.

Errors handling: application checks for possible errors, but does not try to correct them, simply reports. It also is known to leak a socket in certain error conditions (which lead to application shutdown), but adding proper socket close in this case will simply warrant for more code without actually adding a lot of benefit.

Compilation:

```
gcc -std=c99 -g -D_POSIX_SOURCE -Wall -Werror -pedantic -o test_udp send_udp.c
```

Usage: *./test_udp server* or *./test_udp <hostname> <filename>*

Behold: I give you **test_udp.c**.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdint.h>

#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netdb.h>

const short port = 4321;

int run_server();
int send_file(const char* const server, const char* const file);

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    if (argc < 2 || argc > 3) {
        printf("Error: Usage send_udp (server|<server_host>) [<file name>]\n");
        return 1;
    }

    if (!strcmp(argv[1], "server"))
        return run_server(); // runs forever

    if (argc != 3) {
        printf("Error: client mode accepts two arguments: server and file name.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    return send_file(argv[1], argv[2]);
}

int run_server() {
    int sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
    if (sock == -1) {
        printf("run_server(): error creating socket: %s\n", strerror(errno));
        return 2;
    }

    struct sockaddr_in addr;
    addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    addr.sin_port = htons(port);
    addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;

    if (bind(sock, (struct sockaddr*)&addr, sizeof(addr))) {
        printf("run_server(): error binding socket: %s\n", strerror(errno));
        return 2;
    }
    printf("run_server(): socket created and bound, entering endless loop.\n");

    struct sockaddr_in incoming;
    socklen_t incoming_sz = sizeof(incoming);
    char buff[USHRT_MAX]; // maximum size of UDP datagramm
    const char* buff_ptr = buff;
    while (1) {
        ssize_t msg_size = recvfrom(sock, buff, sizeof(buff), 0, (struct sockaddr*)(&incoming), &incoming_sz);
        if (msg_size == -1) {
            printf("run_server(): error receiving message: %s\n", strerror(errno));
            return 3;
        }

        if (msg_size == 0) {
            printf("run_server(): a message of 0 size received from the client, bogus. Skipping, continue to listen.\n");
            continue;
        }

        // Message structure: unsigned 16 bit length of file name (network order), followed by filename, followed by data
        uint16_t fname_len;
        if (msg_size < sizeof(fname_len)) {
            printf("run_server(): Bogus (too short) message received from the client. Skipping, continue to listen.\n");
            continue;
        }

        memcpy(&fname_len, buff_ptr, sizeof(fname_len));
        fname_len = ntohs(fname_len);
        buff_ptr += sizeof(fname_len);
        msg_size -= sizeof(fname_len);
        if (msg_size < fname_len) {
            printf("run_server(): Bogus (too short) message received from the client. Skipping, continue to listen.\n");
            continue;
        }

        char file_name[fname_len + 1];
        strncpy(file_name, buff_ptr, fname_len);
        file_name[fname_len] = '\0';
        buff_ptr += fname_len;
        msg_size -= fname_len;
        printf("run_server(): incoming transfer for file %s, intrinsic file size: %zu\n", file_name, msg_size);

        FILE* f = fopen(file_name, "wb");
        if (!f) {
            printf("run_server(): Could not open file for writing. Skipping the message, carrying on.\n");
            continue;
        }

        size_t written = fwrite(buff_ptr, msg_size, 1, f);
        if (written != 1)
            printf("run_server(): error, could not write whole file.\n");
        else
            printf("run_server(): incoming file written successfully.\n");

        fclose(f);
    }

    return 0;
}

int send_file(const char* const server, const char* const file) {
    uint16_t fname_len = strlen(file);
    uint16_t max_short = 0;
    max_short = ~max_short;
    if (fname_len > (max_short - sizeof(fname_len))) {
        printf("send_file(): file name is toooo large. Can't send this file.\n");
        return 2;
    }
    FILE* f = fopen(file, "rb");
    if (!f) {
        printf("send_file(): Could not open file for reading. Nothing sent.\n");
        return 3;
    }
    fseek(f, 0, SEEK_END);
    unsigned long fsize = ftell(f);
    fseek(f, 0, SEEK_SET);
    if (fsize > max_short - sizeof(fname_len) - fname_len) {
        printf("send_file(): file is toooo large. Can't send this file.\n");
        fclose(f);
        return 2;
    }

    char buff[sizeof(fname_len) + fname_len + fsize];
    char* buff_ptr = buff;
    uint16_t net_fname_len = htons(fname_len);
    memcpy(buff_ptr, &net_fname_len, sizeof(net_fname_len));
    buff_ptr += sizeof(net_fname_len);
    memcpy(buff_ptr, file, fname_len);
    buff_ptr += fname_len;

    size_t rc = fread(buff_ptr, fsize, 1, f);
    if (rc != 1) {
        printf("send_file(): Could not read whole file. Error.\n");
        fclose(f);
        return 3;
    }
    fclose(f);

    struct addrinfo* ainfo;
    if (getaddrinfo(server, NULL, NULL, &ainfo) != 0) {
        printf("send_file(): Unknown host %s.\n", server);
        return 3;
    }
    struct addrinfo* ainfo_begin = ainfo;

    // I will take the first IP v4 entry in possible addressess
    while (ainfo->ai_family != AF_INET && ainfo->ai_next)
        ainfo = ainfo->ai_next;

    if (ainfo->ai_family != AF_INET) {
        printf("send_file(): Couldn't resolve host %s to AF_INET address.\n", server);
        return 3;
    }

    int addr = ((struct sockaddr_in*)(ainfo->ai_addr))->sin_addr.s_addr;
    freeaddrinfo(ainfo_begin);

    int sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
    if (sock == -1) {
        printf("read_file(): error creating socket: %s\n", strerror(errno));
        return 2;
    }

    struct sockaddr_in remote_addr;
    remote_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    remote_addr.sin_port = htons(port);
    remote_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = addr;

    ssize_t sent = sendto(sock, buff, sizeof(buff), 0, (struct sockaddr*)(&remote_addr), sizeof(remote_addr));
    if (sent != sizeof(buff))
        printf("read_file(): error sending message over socket: %s, only %zu bytes sent.\n", strerror(errno), sent);
    else
        printf("read_file(): file sent successfully.\n");

    return sent == sizeof(buff) ? 0 : 3;
}
```